What is this liquid in the engine in the movie Rush?
Around 2:15 mark in Rush (2013), we see a top-down shot of what presumably are the engine cylinders. My question is, what is this liquid in there?

Don't think there is supposed to be any liquid in the open in your typical internal combustion engine. And the vibration makes it seem like it's a liquid.

Looks like some compressed air valves (to replace usual springs), so it shouldn't be a liquid you see there.

Here's a gif I quickly captured

It looks from the gif like it's raining or has been recently raining, could that be relevant?

I don't see that but how could it be relevant? The engines are encased in the body of the car.

Possibly worth asking the question on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

@shim I know the engines used to be exposed and was trying to remember whether that could still have been the case in 1976, but probably not, come to think of it.

Well you can see in the gif some of the cars, and they look pretty enclosed. There certainly are vehicles with exposed engine intakes but it doesn't look like that applies here.

@shim - Elements of some of the engines were exposed; https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Mass_McLaren_10.jpg - I don't know enough about sports cars to answer this question definitely, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "That's rain". Notably we see it raining a few seconds earlier and there's a discussion of using wet weather tyres.

I don't think the parts we're seeing here are among those that are typically exposed, but I don't know enough about it either.

Although, and this is probably obvious in retrospect, but the cars are commonly partially dismantled and reassembled in preparation for the races so it's perfectly reasonable that even if they cover up these parts during the race (which pictures seem to suggest), they could still be exposed before the race like in this image I found (ID 8243). Another image there shows the same car with that part covered (confusing tho bc the cars are clearly lined up and ready to start the race by this point in the film)

I've been looking at his question for two days, ashamed to say "I don't know". I do know they're air intakes, they would be covered at this point before the race… but also because a) I'm a huge F1 fan …& worse, b) I was actually there in that scene. I'm the mechanic who starts the March [I think 7th on the grid for this start; we filmed more than one race start that week.]. BTW, other than they had electric starters retrofitted, which still needed an external battery starter set up to look like an old mechanical one, almost all the cars on the grid are the original cars from 1970.

From strictly a motorsports sense, this is fuel being squirted against the throttle blades. In 1970, the fueling systems used in cars were either carburation or mechanical fuel injection. During the "tip in" (when the throttle blades first open) there is a moment where the rush of air comes into the intake and makes the engine run lean. This can actually make an engine stumble. To compensate, there is fuel squirted directly into the incoming air path to make it richer. This applies to both mechanical fuel injection as well as carburation. Electronic fuel injection had come into being at that time, but was not widely used. In the clip provided by @shim, it appears the engine is being shown "revving", which would inject fuel to compensate.
EDIT:
Those "cones" are open from above. An engine is, for all intents and purposes, an air pump. Air goes in, gets mixed with fuel, gets burned, then goes out the exhaust. Since it's an air pump, air only goes in those cones (velocity stacks) and doesn't come out. Fuel is injected into the air stream as it enters the stacks, which puts it against the throttle plates.
As I stated, the stacks are open from above, but they are still covered by a cowling. The cowling (marked by a red circle) covers this area during racing or even when getting ready to race.

This is why the liquid you see would not be water from rain. They only leave this area uncovered when there's an issue, if they are prepping it to run before a race, or if they are doing a post-race autopsy. In the movie, they are showing this area through "movie magic", as if the cowling wasn't there.
EDIT2:
Here are two short videos pulled from YouTube which hopefully proves my point of why the liquid is fuel on the throttle blades. Neither of the videos is exactly what is being shown in the movie, but the principles are the same. The first video is of a 4-barrel carburetor which is on a dyno. What's good about it is, there are lights being shown down the barrels so you can see the fuel. The second video is of an old BMW engine. This engine has mechanical fuel injection. You can see the injectors at the 6 o'clock position of each "stack".







As someone who once had an ethanol-powered car and had to spray fuel straight into the carburator intake on winter days or it wouldn't even start, I can vouch for the explanation in this answer.

@clvrmnky - This might be part of your point, but most performance engines used in motorsports don't use filters at all.

EDIT: probably not water, see Paulster's answer instead.
Summarizing the discussion in the comments, it might be that the liquid is water from the rain. In the rest of the scene the racers are discussing whether to switch tires because it has been raining.

[Is it going to carry on raining? Or become dry? Should he be
using slicks or wets?].
...
NIKI: What about Hunt? Has he changed?
MECHANIC: No, he's going on wets.

Source: script
Here's a gif of the scene with more context:

While this part of the engine is clearly covered up during the race, prior to the race the cars are assembled and worked on near the track and this part of the engine can be exposed to the elements as shown in this picture of Mike Hailwood's McLaren M23 #33 from 1974:

Source
The same car is shown in the same album with that part covered up:

The race in this part of the movie is from 1970 so it would be a similar design. In fact, the linked album of photos includes a picture of Niki Lauda, one of the main characters of the film, smoking.
The cover helps funnel in fast moving air from the forward motion of the vehicle, and protect the intakes from debris.
Water pooling in the engine like this could in theory be a problem, and presumably the racecar's repair crew would have tried to prevent rain from getting into this high-performance engine. It does seem like a lot of water too. The hot engine would probably quickly evaporate water, plus we see races in this film proceeding in heavy rain (even covered, water could still get in while the car is driving). So I don't know how realistic this would be.
The clip is a bit confusing because the cars are clearly lined up to start the race, and at this point this part of the engine would have already been covered up, but I blame that on the film editing. Could claim that this clip is giving you a peek inside the engine even though it's covered up.

I was curious about whether this was the case, so I asked about it on the mechanics stack exchange and Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 has provided an answer there as well as here saying it's actually not water.
